# DataGridView set CurrentCell not working

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to populate a `DataGridView` and preselect a cell.
But it is not working well.
I'm creating the `DataGridView` with this code:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Column1");
table.Columns.Add("Column2");
table.Rows.Add("Row1");
table.Rows.Add("Row2");
table.Rows.Add("Row3");
table.Rows.Add("Row3");
table.Rows.Add("Row4");
table.Rows.Add("");

dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;
dataGridView1.Columns["Column1"].ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1[1, 2].ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1[1, 3].ReadOnly = true;

DataGridViewButtonCell button = new DataGridViewButtonCell();
dataGridView1[1, table.Rows.Count - 1] = button;
button.Value = "Go";
button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;

dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, 1];
```

In theory the first cell on the right side should be selected but the 3rd row in the 1st column is selected.
Could this problem result with this:

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Or

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

}
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the following

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, 1];
```

and say

> In theory the first cell on the right side should be selected

In fact, the arguments for the cell indexer are `columnIndex, rowIndex`, so the above should select the first column of the second row, which it indeed does. Use `dataGridView[1, 0]` if you intend to select the second column of the first row.

Comment: I've testeted dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, 0];

Bute the 2nd column and the 2nd row was selected.
It's like he don't know the first row.

Comment: @ComanderKai77 When does the method above get executed - form constructor, load event or?

Comment: In the Form1_Load I call method with this code you mean.

Comment: @ComanderKai77 Well, I've tried exactly the code you posted, and it works as expected - inside the form load event it selects exactly the cell I specify. Make sure you are not executing some other code from the grid events that selects another cell.

Comment: Thank you, I found the bug.

Comment: The Problem was 'dataGridView1_KeyDown' because i wanted to catch enter, but it first run the my custom KeyDown code and then acts to the enter action and switched to the next row.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to set the `dataGridView1.CurrentCell` you should note that in the `dataGridView1[0, 1]` first number is the `columnIndex` and second number is the `rowIndex`. So if you want to select the first cell on the right side you should try this:

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1,0];//first row second column
```